how to fill same named form fields with itext7 without losing formatting
I'm somewhat new to itext7, I ran into an issue trying to fill a form.
Take a PDF, put multiple PDF Text fields on there with the same name but different fonts.  Say a field called "test" with a font verdana 10pt and another field called "test" with a font verdana 6pt.  Save that field.
The point of the software is to take a form and fill it, so from there the code should run and fill those fields.  It does, but whatever the formatting of the first field is (that has formatting at least) that will be copied to all the other ones after it so that you lose the formatting that the document should have.
Here is my code:
Dictionary<string, string> fieldValues = new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
fieldValues["testField"] = "This is a value";
using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(sourcePdf))
{
    using (PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(destPdf))
    {
        using (PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument(reader, writer))
        {
            PdfAcroForm form = PdfAcroForm.GetAcroForm(document, false);
            if (form == null)
                return;

            var fields = form.GetAllFormFields();

            foreach (PdfFormField field in fields.Select(m => m.Value))
            {
                string fieldName = field.GetFieldName().ToString();
                if (field is PdfTextFormField textField && fieldValues.ContainsKey(fieldName))
                    field.SetValue(fieldValues[fieldName]);
            }
            document.Close();
        }
        writer.Close();
    }
    reader.Close();
}

before and after screen clippings have been attached
before
after

@KJ, Is what you are saying that iText does not support using field.SetValue(""); to set fields with different formatting?  Keep in mind, I am not trying to create a PDF with this code, I am starting with a template.
Is the point of the naming you gave me so that I could set the value of all three just by running that method for "test", or so that I could set each individually (set value for "test.P0.#0", "test.P0.#1"...)

That makes a lot of sense, but I'm thinking there is still a difference in what I'm seeing.  Debugging I'm seeing that iText is not recognizing the fonts.  When I look at the before fields in an editor, I'm seeing that the parent had the font Helvetica pt 0, child 1 Helvetica 6, child 2 Helvetica 14.  In the after I see parent has Helvetica 0, but only one child which is Helvetica 6, and that child has a bunch of children with no formatting (I'm no expert on PDF formatting, but I don't think that is right).  Could it be a bug I'm running into?
